# Positioning ChartLabels in a horizontal stacked BarChart

Tags: plotting, charts

I can create a `BarChart` with horizontal bars (using `BarOrigin -> Left`) and *Mathematica* will automatically position the `ChartLabels` on the left hand side:

```
data1D = RandomReal[{1, 10}, 10];
labels = DictionaryLookup["D*", 10];

BarChart[data1D, BarOrigin -> Left, ChartLabels -> labels, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Calibri", 14}]
```

[image]

However, if I want to plot a stacked chart in the same way, the `ChartLabels` appear below the bars:

```
data2D = RandomReal[{1, 10}, {10, 2}];

BarChart[data2D, BarOrigin -> Left, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
 ChartLabels -> {labels, None}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Calibri", 14}]
```

[image]

How can I get the labels for the stacked chart to appear as they do in the simple chart?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
 ChartLabels -> {Placed[labels, Axis], None}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! I looked at `Placed` but didn't see `Axis` in the docs. Accepting immediately as this is 100% what I wanted.

Comment: Simon, thank you for the accept. I have been struggling with option combinations  `BarOrigin`/`Joined` in `BarCharts`/`Histograms`; somehow `Joined->True` works properly only if `BarOrigin->Bottom` (perhaps due to some corruption in my mma installation). Do you mind checking if `Joined->True` works as expected in your example?

Comment: I can confirm that `Joined->True` does **not** work properly on my example (MMA 8.04).

Comment: fixed in version 9.